# How do I determine the current layout in Middleman 4?

Tags: middleman, middleman-4

Up through Middleman 3 I could determine the layout of the current page like this.

```
current_page.data.layout
```

As of Middleman 4 this no longer works. How can I determine what the current layout is in 4+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Middleman 4, you can access the `layout` of a resource with `resource.options[:layout]`.